# Showing CustomViews properly in Graphical Layout of android xml

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have made a very simple Custom TextView. Everything works fine in android device. However on graphical layout of eclipse All I can see is the class name written instead of TextView original Text. How Can I test it in eclipse graphical layout?

Below is my code

```
public class MyTextView extends TextView 
{

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) 
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) 
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context) 
    {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init() 
    {
        //if (!isInEditMode())
        {
            Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "HelveticaLTStd-Bold.otf");
            setTypeface(tf);
            this.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFD200"));
            this.setShadowLayer(1, 1, 1, Color.BLACK);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i had the same problem with custom fonts on custom textViews.

the graphical editor is quite buggy and lacks many features that work fine on real devices.

this is one example of such a thing.

in order to fix it , just don't load fonts when isInEditMode() returns true, and ignore how the text looks like.

in fact, maybe the shadow feature also doesn't work well, so you might want to add it too.

Comment: maybe it will get fixed some day. also, maybe the new IDE can handle those cases : http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html .

Comment: does the shadow feature work on the graphical editor? i don't remember.